# How to retain pagination page in Node blog app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am building a blog site using Express. It has an edit and delete features. I am trying to redirect to the same page of the pagination I left off in the root route upon deleting or editing an existing post. As it stands now, if I delete a post on Page 2 for example, it will redirect me back to Page 1. The same thing will happen if I delete a blog post on Page 2. But I want both functionalities to redirect back to Page 2. Any help is appreciated.

This is the Edit page on the front-end.

```
<form action="/edit/<%=id %>?_method=PUT?page=<%= currentPage %>" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="postTitle">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="postTitle" class="form-control" id="postTitle" autocomplete="off" value="<%= title %>">
    <label for="postBody">Post</label>
    <textarea name="postBody" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" rows="8"><%= content %></textarea>
  </div>
    <button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
</form>
```

Here is the form for the Delete function on the front-end.

```
  <form action="/delete?page=<%= currentPage %>" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="delete" value="<%= post._id %>" class="btn btn-outline-danger">DELETE</button>
  </form>
```

Here is the root, delete and edit routes on the back-end.

```
// Root route that displays all posts stored in database.
app.get("/", (req, res) => {

  let perPage = 3;
  let totalItems;
  let currentPage = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;

  Post.find()
    .countDocuments()
    .then(count => {

      totalItems = count;

      Post.find()
        .sort({ date: -1 })
        .skip((currentPage - 1) * perPage)
        .limit(perPage)
        .then(posts => {
          console.log(currentPage);
          res.render("home", {
            posts,
            currentPage,
            totalItems
          });

        });
    })
});


// Route for updating specific post.
app.put('/edit/:id', (req, res) => {
  let currentPage = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
  const postEdit = {
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody
  };
  Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, postEdit, (err, post) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.redirect("/?page=" + currentPage);
    }
  });
});

// Route for deleting specific post.
app.post("/delete", (req, res) => {
  const deletePost = req.body.delete;
  let currentPage = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
  Post.findByIdAndRemove(deletePost, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.redirect("/?page=" + currentPage);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: you can pass some additional data to your `/delete` route  as a query parameter from client Eg. `<form action="/delete?page=2" method="POST">`. And then use it in your `delete` route as `let currentPage = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;` same as what you are doing in your `/` route

Comment: Check the value of currentPage in delete route. Where did you declared currentPage variable in delete route.

Comment: The currentPage variable is in the root GET route up top. Every time I change routes, the currentPage variable always goes back to the first page.

Comment: @Abhas Tandon, I tried it and it gave me a ```Cannot GET /1``` error.

Comment: @envincebal you mean after the item is deleted you are being redirected to `/1`? Can you share your updated code? Also, your `currentPage` varialble is local to '/' route it won't be available in `/delete` route

Comment: @Abhas Tandon, yeah that's exactly it. I updated the code in my OP.

Comment: @Abhas Tandon Oh wait, nevermind.  It works. Sorry about that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @envincebal glad that it worked, submitted the first comment as answer

Comment: @Abhas Tandon yeah thanks. But the "edit" route is still not working and it's a bit more tricky. I updated the code. Would you mind looking at that real quick?

Comment: `<form action="/edit/<%=id %>?_method=PUT&page=<%= currentPage %>" method="POST">` query params follow format: `?param1=value1&param2=value2` they are `&` delimited

Comment: @Abhas Tandon I tried that, but it says ```currentPage isn't defined```. Even though, I added the variable into the edit route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good idea to just send status while hitting API's rather than redirecting from API it self. I would recommend you to do the same. Once you hit the API in your client, you will get http status code like 200(success) or 500(something went wrong while performing action) or what so ever.Depending on http status code do redirections on client side only(if needed).

```
app.put('/edit/:id', (req, res) => {

 const postEdit = {
  title: req.body.postTitle,
  content: req.body.postBody
 };

Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, postEdit, (err, post) => {
   if (err) {
   console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(err);
   } else {
    res.status(200).send();// send status only 
   }
 });
});

// Route for deleting specific post.
app.post("/delete", (req, res) => {
 const deletePost = req.body.delete;

  Post.findByIdAndRemove(deletePost, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(err);
  } else {
    res.status(200).send(); // send status only 
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass some additional data to your `/delete` route as a query parameter from client Eg.

`<form action="/delete?page=2" method="POST">`

Instead of `2` you can pass the actual page from your backend in model and use it in the view.

And then use it in your `delete` route as `let currentPage = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;` same as what you are doing in your`/` route

```
app.post("/delete", (req, res) => {
  const deletePost = req.body.delete;
  let currentPage = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1; // you need to get the value here for this route

  Post.findByIdAndRemove(deletePost, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.redirect('/?page=' + currentPage);
    }
  });
```